# how to solve "Error: Syntax error in input(1)."

Tags: python, swig

i don't have an experience with using swig.i'm trying to run .py file using swig. I have executed the command like in terminal

```
 swig -python filename.py
```

but i'm getting the error "Error: Syntax error in input(1)." How to solve the error which i mentioned the above.Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: share the contents of `filename` to get better answer

Comment: Swig does not take a Python file as input.  It takes a Swig interface file.  Read the [documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html).

Answer (score 1):

Look at [34.2 Preliminaries](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_nn2): it clearly indicates that you have to do either `swig -python yourfile.i` or `swig -c++ -python yourfile.i` you need to create a `module.i` for your C++ DLL. Then you run SWIG on the .i, which creates another .cpp file. Finally, you compile this .cpp file into a DLL which you link with Python DLL. Then in your `filename.py` you can import your module, and you can do `python filename.py`.